# How to disable Eclipse E3 application Maximum button

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have requirement to disable Maximum button, I have below code in ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class, but still Maximum button is enabled

```
@Override
    public void preWindowOpen() {
        IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
        configurer.setInitialSize(new Point(800, 500));
        configurer.setShowCoolBar(true);
        configurer.setShowStatusLine(true);
        configurer.setShellStyle(SWT.TITLE | SWT.CLOSE | SWT.MIN);
}
```

Comment: I believe the configurer shell style is ignored in Eclipse 4 - see [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432501)

Comment: Thanks.. Any alternate to disable max button?

Comment: You might be able to use [styleOverride](http://blog.vogella.com/2014/03/17/using-eclipse-application-model-persisted-state-to-specify-the-swt-stylebits/) in the LegacyIDE.e4xmi. This works for e4 rcps, I haven't tried it for e3. Note that on some platforms (macOS for example) you can't completely disable maximise as it is used for things like "enter full screen"

Comment: Thanks Greg, any comments on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267235/capture-minimize-and-maximize-button-click-of-eclipse-e3-application